# PowerPoint Shape Issues - Arrows Off Center and Join/Cap Types Unresponsive

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, shapes

I've got the same issue as what's referenced here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562386/ms-powerpoint-arrows-are-off-center#new-answer

Looks like that user hasn't posted on this side yet, but I will, because I've been using PowerPoint for years without having this issue. Since the only other reference I can find to this problem is earlier this month, I wonder if this is caused by a glitch in the last update (or maybe an overworked graphics card?).

Essentially, [these things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogVGf.png) started happening all at once:

- Shape lines don't join smoothly; unresponsive to changes in Cap type
  or Join type.
- Selected lines appear at half-weight (the line selected in the [attached snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogVGf.png) is the same weight as the connector, and appears that way when deselected).
- Begin/End Arrows are off-center.
- Join type not applied the same at all connector elbows.

Is there some default setting that may have changed?  In Visio I would be able to change the pin position, but PowerPoint doesn't give the user control of this to my knowledge, and that wouldn't affect the corners of the default shapes.

Does anyone know what's going on here?? The version I'm using is 2013.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Discovered what was going on (at least to some extent).  Though I haven't found the control to change these specific settings, they do seem to be tied to the Theme applied to the presentation.  Specifically, the themes "Crop," "Badge," and "Headline" all cause the shapes and arrows to behave this way.

I applied a different theme and just re-applied my color palatte and fonts. Had to make adjustments to the master to get the exact look I wanted, but it fixed the shape issues.

If anyone knows where the controls are for these settings, or if they're accessible in VBA, please let me know!

Comment: If you have a question, you should submit it as a question, not as an answer to another question.  Considering modifying your answer so it only answers the author's question instead of asking your own question(s).

Comment: It's not a different question- read what I wrote.  I posted the workaround I found, but in my original question I was looking for any method to change the settings that were causing the issues.  Changing the entire Theme of a presentation worked to fix the issues I experienced, but it can cause a host of other problems to fix if the other visual elements in your presentation are tied to the theme.  It's the same freaking question reiterated; just because I cited VBA as a possible solution doesn't make it different.  And BTW, it's ridiculous to downvote an actual answer for procedural reasons.

Comment: "If anyone knows where the controls are for these settings, or if they're accessible in VBA, please let me know!" This comment doesn't belong in answer.  If you want to know where the settings are, ask your own question, because it's not possible to tell you where the settings are except in a comment. Comments should not be used to answer questions. Voting is anonymous.  It appears you have multiple accounts, you should merge them, so people are not confused.  *So I encourage you to ask a question if you want to know where the settings are.*

Comment: When you remove the commentary from your answer, the downvote can be reversed, a vote can't be reversed until the answer is edited